# Show loading image before div with multiple content is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I am trying to show loading image before divs with highcharts are loaded.

This is the image which I want to load:

```
<div class="preload">
<img src="{{ asset('/img/ajax-loader.gif') }}" id="image" />
</div>
```

This is div with highcharts:

```
<div class="content">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div id="runs_bms_verlauf" style="width: 1300px; height: 350px; margin: 0 auto;">
            </div>
        </div>
           <div class="clear" style="margin-top: 25px"></div>

        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div id="column_channel" style="width: 1300px; height: 350px; margin: 0 auto;">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="spacer">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div id="column_days" style="width: 1300px; height: 350px; margin: 0 auto;">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="spacer">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div id="pie_runs_zeit" style="width: 1300px; height: 350px; margin-top: 100px">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

And my jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".content").on('load', function(){
  $(".preload img").fadeOut(200, function(){
    $(".content").fadeIn(10000)
  })
});
</script>
```

But nothing actually happens. Image is shown and the loading gif is spinning, after that content is loaded and image doesn't fadeOut... It remains above highcharts

Comment: See the duplicate